# How do I fix Xcode build error "no such module 'myModule'" at "import myModule" in my Swift app after adding a swift static lib .a to my swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, import

I have a swift app project.
I create and build a swift static lib with

```swift
public func test() {
    print("hello world")
}
```

I add `.a` to app project Build Phases > Link Binary with Lib.. > (+) > myModule.a

I add `import myModule` and a call to `test()` in my view controller.
Build.
get error.

Comment: May be a missing interface declaring the test func.

Comment: Would be useful to see the error log.

Comment: Ptit: did you mean the .swiftmodule ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was because I failed to add the .swiftmodule to the app and I didn't set Swift Compiler - Search Paths > Import Paths.

1. .swiftmodule file must be in same folder as .a file.
   ie. In swift app project, do Xcode command to add files and select *BOTH* .a and .swiftmodule files.
2. Build Settings > "Search Paths" > Swift Compiler - Search Paths > Import Paths: must have path to .a's folder.